# How can I get my divs to process separately?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Not sure exactly how to put this but here goes. I have a page that I set up to show and hide divs when a certain link is clicked and everything is working fairly well apart from this. when the first two links are pressed, the div that appears becomes linked the same as the last link on the page. Likewise the third is linked the same way and also has underline and white text (as I set up for general links on the site)

The div that shows up when a link is clicked shouldn't be linked at all.

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
    <div id="shown" class="content">
        <div id="list">
            <div id="filler"></div>
            <a href="javascript:show('shown','id1','a1');"><div id="a1" class="inactive">WHAT IS LIGHT IT UP?</div></a>
            <div id="spacer"></div>
            <a href="javascript:show('shown','id2','a2');"><div id="a2" class="inactive">WHO</div></a>
            <div id="spacer"></div>
            <a href="javascript:show('shown','id3','a3');"><div id="a3" class="inactive">REGISTRATION FEES</div></a>
            <div id="spacer"></div>
            <a href="javascript:show('shown','id4','a4');"><div id="a4" class="inactive">WHEN</div></a>
            <div id="spacer"></div>
            <a href="javascript:show('shown','id5','a5');"><div id="a5" class="inactive">AWARDS</div></a>
            <div id="spacer"></div>
            <a href="javascript:show('shown','id6','a6');"><div id="a6" class="inactive">GLOW DANCE PARTY!</div>
            <div id="filler"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="id1" class="hidden">text 1</div>
        <div id="id2" class="hidden">text 2</div>
        <div id="id3" class="hidden">text 3</div>
        <div id="id4" class="hidden">text 4</div>
        <div id="id5" class="hidden">text 5</div>
        <div id="id6" class="hidden">text 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{width:94%; float:left; position:relative; left:3%; background-color:rgba(163,207,98,0.7); margin:auto; border-radius:1.2em;}
#container{width:96%; float:left; position:relative; left:2%; margin-top:2%;}

#spacer{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); float:left; box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);}
#filler{height:1.5em; width:100%;}
#list{
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-family:upc;
    font-size:1.35em;
}
#list a:link{text-decoration:none}
.active{
    text-shadow: -2px 1px 1px #000;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color:#A3CF62;
}
.inactive{
    text-shadow: -2px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    color:#000;
}

.inactive:hover{
    text-shadow: -2px 1px 1px #000;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color:#A3CF62;
    border-radius:2em;
}
.hidden {display: none}
.unhidden {
    margin-top:1.5em;
    margin-bottom:1.5em;
    display:block;
    text-align:justify;
    color:#A3CF62;
}

#shown{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius:1.2em;
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape){
    #list{width:20%; text-align: center; position:relative; float:left; right:20%;}
    #shown{width:80%; float:left; left:20%;}
    #spacer {
        width:90%;
        margin-top:0.1em;
        margin-bottom:0.1em;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        height:0.1em;
    }
    #stretch{display:none}
    .unhidden{width:80%; vertical-align: middle; float:left; position:relative; right:10%; overflow-y:auto;}
    .active{border-top-left-radius:2em; border-bottom-left-radius:2em;}
}
```

JavaScript

```
var old_target,old_trigger;
function show(win, target, trigger){
    document.getElementById(win).className = 'content';
    if(old_target!==undefined) document.getElementById(old_target).className = 'hidden';
    if(old_trigger!==undefined) document.getElementById(old_trigger).className = 'inactive';
    document.getElementById(target).className = 'unhidden';
    document.getElementById(trigger).className = 'active';
    old_target = target;
    old_trigger = trigger;
}
```

Comment: Just glancing at it, it's always a BAD idea to have multiple DOM elements with the same ID.

Comment: It's not valid html to have divs inside a-elements... but with a quick I saw that you're missing a closeing </a> at <a href="javascript:show('shown','id6','a6');"><div id="a6" class="inactive">GLOW DANCE PARTY!</div>

Comment: haha that was my first thought was I had a missing tag, but I swore I checked it over thoroughly >.< thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last `<a href>` element is missing its closing tag, causing the browser's HTML parser to generate unexpected results. To see the unintended effect, select 'Inspect element' from the right-click menu.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Again, I thought I checked all of my tags, but that one obviously escaped me haha.